# What is the difference in meaning between "students in universities" and "students at universities"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

According to [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=students%20in%20universities%2Cstudents%20at%20universities&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstudents%20in%20universities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstudents%20at%20universities%3B%2Cc0) both "students **in** universities" and "students **at** universities" are used.  I wonder whether there is a difference in meaning.

*The Independent:*

> There are more than 150 million **students in universities** around the world, yet academic expertise has rarely been less trusted

*The Guardian:*

> **Students at universities** across the United States participated in protests to demand their schools refrain from using facial recognition on campus.

*The Independent:*

> To illustrate the absurdity of these claims, consider the current proportion of poorer **students at universities** such as Oxford.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: There is a tendency for US speakers to prefer 'in school/college' and British speakers to prefer 'at school/college/university', but there is some overlap.